# Download text file, and save as a string in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I recently started to programming javascript on server side(node js), and i have a really simple trouble, that i can't solve :S

I want to download a txt file, and save it as a string  variable. This is my atempt:

```
var consensus;
http.get('random/url/consensus.txt' , function(res) {
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        consensus = ('BODY: ' + chunk);});
    });
console.log(consensus)
```

When i run the script it said "consensus" is undefined, but when i change `consensus = ('BODY: ' + chunk);});` this line to this `console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);});` its print out the string (file) that i want to save as string. Ohh before i forget to mention, I want to find a solution only with the standard libs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your console.log is OUTSIDE the callback, therefor it gets called right after you initiate the call before the callback is happening.

Try doing something like this: (I am not so sure on the events names)

```
var req = http.get(......) //rest of code stays the same

req.on('end', function() {console.log(consensus);});
```

I think it should solve your problems.

And try to read more about the async nature of nodeJS.